# Which of the following quadratic forms defines a non-singular conic?

Tags: geometry, projective-geometry

Which of the following quadratic forms defines a non-singular conic?

(1). $x_{0}^{2}-2x_{0}x_{1}+4x_{0}x_{2}-8x_{1}^{2}+2x_{1}x_{2}+4x_{2}^{2}$.
(2). $x_{0}^{2}-4x_{0}x_{1}+x_{1}^{2}-2x_{0}x_{2}$.

What is a good way to solve this problem? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matrix for the first conic is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 & 2 \\
-1 & -8 & 1 \\
2 & 1 & 4
\end{bmatrix}
$$
which has determinant $-9$.

The matrix for the second conic is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -2 & -1 \\
-2 & 1 & 0 \\
-1 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
which has determinant $-1$.

So neither is singular.

Comment: How did you get these matrices?

Comment: @user315141 It's the standard symmetric matrix associated to a quadratic form